# display multiple records in one column in grid view

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net

I want to display multiple records in a single column in grid view. I have use a label to display the records in the grid view but it just show one record only.
Here are the records in database and the grid view (the yellow that i highlighted is for display the records.

database records

[image: enter link description here]

grid view

[image: enter link description here]

Below are the code,

```
conn.Open();


        SqlCommand cmd3 = new SqlCommand("select t_purpose from Trip",conn);

        SqlDataReader reader2 = cmd3.ExecuteReader();

        if (reader2.Read())
        {
            lblpurpose.Text = reader2.GetString(0);


        }
```

Hope that someone could help me. I'm new to asp.net and mysql.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Highlight the problem and we'll give you a hand. Please see [ask] and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/495455

Comment: You want to show comma separated ?

Comment: Yes. Is that possible to show multiple records in one label? For example I have two records for destination which are London and New York. Can I display two of the records in a single label with comma as well? @Krishna

Comment: Yes try the below answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
select t_purpose+',' from Trip for xml path('')
```

This will give comma separated list. If you want space change it in query

Comment: It working. Thank you. The thing that I want is just simple but I come out with complex question.. Sorry for that.